# Bringing Beer into the Philipines

Tags: customs-and-immigration, alcohol, philippines

I will be travelling to the Phillipines soon and I am unsure about what the rules are for bringing in Beer. Official sources are a bit conflicting, so I was wondering if anyone here knew what applies?

What are the limits for bringing in Beer duty free (and non-commerical purposes)? If I exceed those what can I expect to happen?

I'm planning to bring in 6 cans of local Beer as a gift for someone I know there, of about 2 litres in total and a total value of about $10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the trip is done.I talked to the customs people when I landed and they informed me that the limit is only for stronger drinks, beer has no restrictions.

Comment: Which makes sense with the 2 bottles (1 litre max) restriction. Did they give any info on what counts as strong enough (Wine/foritfied wine/liquer/spirit?). Any pointing to where you could find out.

Comment: They did not specify, but I brought quite strong beer (about 8.5%, clearly printed on the cans). I do not know how they categorize things no.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the IATA travel centre](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ph-philippines-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) the duty free alcohol import limits are 2 bottles of maximum 1 litre each. Quoting from the linked website:

> ### Customs Rules
>
> #### Import regulations::
>
> Free import:
>
> 1. all passengers (18 years of age and over) (duty free allowance only once per year per passenger):
>
>    a. 400 cigarettes or 50 cigars or 250 grammes pipe tobacco;
>
>    b. 2 bottles alcoholic beverages of not more than 1 litre each

It would therefore seem that you'll have to pay import duty on the exceeding cans of beer. According to the [online duty calculator](http://m.dutycalculator.com/dc/186244559/food-drinks/drinks-other-alcoholic-beverages/beer-in-containers-4-litres-not-in-bottles/import-duty-rate-for-importing-draft-beers-from-france-to-philippines-is-15/), duty for beer is 15% plus sales tax of 12%.